# Autoencoder Dimensionality Error

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

Thanks for taking a look!

I have an auto-encoder that I am trying to use for anomaly detection.  I have 2 log files, logfile.log and testfile.log.  They're essentially the same logfile, I just split them for training and testing purposes.  The logfile consists of millions of lines, where each line is an log entry or observation.

I have already preprocessed the files a little bit, such that they are JSON dictionaries where each line is a dictionary representing an observation and each key represents a value in the dictionary.  They are nested, but in my code I flatten it for simplicity's sake.

My goal is to train the autoencoder on logfile.log and then run the model against testfile.log line by line and outputting the reconstruction error.  Depending on how large the reconstruction error is, I will flag it.  (Haven't started on that portion yet)

**Model:**

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
import os
import json
from flatten_json import flatten
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


vartime=time.time()
log_file = './logfile.log'
def seedy(s):
    np.random.seed(s)
    set_random_seed(s)
decshape = 0
class AutoEncoder:
    def __init__(self, encoding_dim=31):
        self.encoding_dim = encoding_dim
        #r = lambda: np.random.randint(1, 5)
        newdata = [] 

        with open(log_file, 'r') as file:
            counter = 0
            buffer = ''
            data = []
            print(np.intp)
            text = file.readlines(40000000)
            for line in text:
                data = []
                counter = counter+1
                buffer=json.loads(line)
                buffer = flatten(buffer)
                if counter%50000 == 0:
                    print(counter)
                    print(time.time()-vartime)
                data.append((buffer.get("Key1","None")))
                data.append((buffer.get("Key2","None")))
                data.append((buffer.get("Key3","None")))
                data.append(int((buffer.get("Key4","None"))[11:12]))
                data.append((buffer.get("key4", "None")))
                data.append((buffer.get("key5","None")))
                data.append((buffer.get("key6","None")))
                newdata.append(data)
                #print("TEST\n")
                #print(newdata)

        self.x = np.array(newdata)
        labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()        
        self.x[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(self.x[:,0])

        labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()        
        self.x[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(self.x[:, 1])

        labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()        
        self.x[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(self.x[:, 2])

        labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()        
        self.x[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(self.x[:, 4])

        labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()        
        self.x[:, 5] = labelencoder_X_5.fit_transform(self.x[:, 5])

        labelencoder_X_6 = LabelEncoder()        
        self.x[:, 6] = labelencoder_X_6.fit_transform(self.x[:, 6])
        self.x = keras.utils.to_categorical(self.x, dtype='float32') 

        #X_train, X_test = train_test_split(self.x, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 0)

    def _encoder(self):
        inputs = Input(shape=(self.x[0].shape))
        #keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        encoded = Dense(self.encoding_dim, activation='relu')(inputs)
        model = Model(inputs, encoded)
        self.encoder = model
        return model

    def _decoder(self):
        decshape = self.x.shape[2]
        inputs = Input(shape=(self.encoding_dim,))
        decoded = Dense(decshape)(inputs)
        model = Model(inputs, decoded)
        self.decoder = model
        return model

    def encoder_decoder(self):
        ec = self._encoder()
        dc = self._decoder()

        inputs = Input(shape=self.x[0].shape)
        ec_out = ec(inputs)
        dc_out = dc(ec_out)
        model = Model(inputs, dc_out)

        self.model = model
        return model

    def fit(self, batch_size=10000, epochs=300):
        self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='MSE')
        log_dir = './log/'
        tbCallBack = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
        self.model.fit(self.x, self.x,
            epochs=epochs,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            callbacks=[tbCallBack])

    def save(self):
        if not os.path.exists(r'./weights'):
            os.mkdir(r'./weights')
        else:
            self.encoder.save(r'./weights/encoder_weights.h5')
            self.decoder.save(r'./weights/decoder_weights.h5')
            self.model.save(r'./weights/ae_weights.h5')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seedy(2)
    ae = AutoEncoder(encoding_dim=2)
    ae.encoder_decoder()
    ae.fit(batch_size=10000, epochs=300)
    ae.save()
```

**Testing:**

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import json
from flatten_json import flatten
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import time

vartime = time.time()
encoder = load_model(r'./weights/encoder_weights.h5')
decoder = load_model(r'./weights/decoder_weights.h5')

log_file = "./testfile.log"

hold =[]
with open(log_file, 'r') as file:
     counter = 0
     buffer = ''
     data = []
     newdata =     []
     text = file.readlines(40000000)
     for line in text:
          data = []
          counter = counter+1
          buffer=json.loads(line)
          buffer = flatten(buffer)
          if counter%50000 == 0:
               print(counter)
               print(time.time()-vartime)
          data.append((buffer.get("Key1","None")))
          data.append((buffer.get("Key2","None")))
          data.append((buffer.get("Key3","None")))
          data.append(int((buffer.get("Key4","None"))[11:12]))
          data.append((buffer.get("Key5", "None")))
          data.append((buffer.get("Key6","None")))
          data.append((buffer.get("Key7","None")))
          newdata.append(data)
          #print("TEST\n")
          #print(newdata)

newdata = np.array(newdata)
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
newdata[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(newdata[:,0])

labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
newdata[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(newdata[:, 1])

labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
newdata[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(newdata[:, 2])

labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()
newdata[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(newdata[:, 4])

labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()
newdata[:, 5] = labelencoder_X_5.fit_transform(newdata[:, 5])

labelencoder_X_6 = LabelEncoder()
newdata[:, 6] = labelencoder_X_6.fit_transform(newdata[:, 6])

newdata = keras.utils.to_categorical(newdata, dtype='float32')

inputs = newdata[0]
x = encoder.predict(inputs)
y = decoder.predict(x)

print('Input: {}'.format(inputs))
print('Encoded: {}'.format(x))
print('Decoded: {}'.format(y))
```

**Error when running the testing portion:**

x = encoder.predict(inputs)

'with shape ' + str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_8 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (7, 31)

Note:
When I do "inputs = newdata" to make it 3 dimensions, I get the same error but saying a 2d array was expected.  I've even tried using logfile.log as the test file for the testing portion, as it's literally the same thing used in the training.

I also changed the actual key names to Key1, key2, key3... etc. as if I did not, the code looked extremely messy.  I do know that I am correctly reading the files and one-hot encoding everything correctly.  That shouldn't be the issue, but I can re-implement the original key names if absolutely necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if any more information is needed, or if this is the wrong place for this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I know how to accomplish my intended goal, but I can say that my approach was faulty.  The prediction in an auto-encoder is for regenerating the input, adding another prediction in the testing phase is rather wonky.

I will continue looking into ways to develop reconstruction error.